# Cannot send response outside the for each loop in async firebase method

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Cannot send response outside the for each loop in async firebase method. When I send a response in the for-each loop, it gives only once, but I need the whole array at the end of the program.

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

let db = admin.firestore();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest(function(request, response) {
  var dat = [];
  var dat1 = [];
  db.collection("users")
    .get()
    .then(function(snapshot) {
      dat.push(element.id);
      return snapshot;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });
  dat.forEach(element => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(element.id)
      .collection("profile")
      .doc(element.id)
      .collection("pet")
      .doc(element.id)
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        dat1.push(snapshot.data()["bio"]);
        return snapshot;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Error getting documents", err);
      });
  });
  response.send(dat1);
});
```

I have to get an array of data from the firebase database. When I send the response, it returns an empty array, as shown in the above example. I am a beginner to Javascript and nodejs programming.

Comment: ...and which variable are you talking about?

Comment: @Lee Taylor I edited this question. I cannot send response

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question. The problem you have is that you are running asynchronous actions inside the `forEach` loop and running `response.send` Synchronously. You need to wait for all the asynchronous operations to finish before responding. Try using `Promise.all` to handle the requests of all the promises you are generating. Then, run the `response.send` command inside its response handler.

Comment: @guzmonne I am a beginner to javascript (node.js). Can you please help me to implement promise.all feature.

Comment: You should start by learning how promises work in JavaScript. This is a great link with to do so: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise. You can then find information regarding the `Promise.all` interface on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise/all.

Comment: Understanding promises and working with them correctly is very important to writing effective JavaScript, especially in Cloud Functions.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/